# How do I insert information into different columns for the same record in SQL?

Tags: sql

I would like to create a record in a table using VBA and add different information that pertains to the record in different column.

Currently my code creates a new record and gives it a name. Now under the same record I would like to add an Address. How can this be done?

Here my code inserts the value 'Testing VB' into Name in the table customer. How can I add an address to this same customer?

```
sSQL = "Insert into customer (Name) values ('Testing VB')"
```

Comment: Update the record? Add another field to the insert? This is basic SQL in any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want insert in the same  time

```
Insert into customer (Name, Address) values ('Testing VB', 'My address')
```

if you want add after you have performed  the insert you need  an update

```
 update customer 
 set address = 'My Addres'
 where Name  = 'Testing VB'
```